# If statement in bash to check if column matches string

Tags: bash, if-statement, cut

I'm relatively new to scripting in general, and I'm running into a bit of a problem. I have this snippet of code that is used in one of our csv manipulation scripts. See below.

```
if [[ '$349' = ’Negative’ ]] || [[ '$349' = ’Positive’ ]] || [[ '$349' = ’Pending’ ]]
then
    echo "neg/pos"
    cut -d, -f 5,6,247,348,352 "$f" > "${f}.tmp"
else
    echo "apc/etc"
    cut -d, -f 5,6,247,349,353 "$f" > "${f}.tmp"
fi
mv ${f}.tmp /home/Outgoing/$f
rm -f $f
```

Basically have a large csv file that is generated in our app, and I want to check the contents of column 349. If it contains either "Negative", "Positive", or "Pending" it will cut the file down to the five columns in the then statement.

If not, it will cut them to the 5 columns in the else statement.

I have a test file running through it. Column 349 clearly has "Negative" inside the file, but it keeps through it to the else statement.

Can someone help? I feel like I'm missing something very simple.

Thank you!

Comment: so you pass the csv into your program as program arguments? wow.

Comment: passing your csv as program arguments is fundamentally error prone. that potentially contributes to your error.

Comment: First, you need double quotes, not single quotes. Second, a multi-digit positional parameter requires braces: `${349}`, not `$349`. Finally, are you actually passing 349+ arguments to your script, or are you doing something else that you *assume* that `${349}` would reference the 349th column of some unspecified line? You need to show how you are actually running your script.

Comment: Like I said I'm pretty new to all of this. I didn't build the bases of these scripts, and I'm not much a programmer at all. Yes, my assupmtion was that $349 was referencing column 349 in the file. Is that not correct?

Comment: @CodyThomas The shell doesn't have any built-in concept of columns;`${349}` refers to the 349th *argument* to the script (or, if it occurs in a function, the 349th argument to the script). It's possible some other part of the script is somehow converting columns to arguments, but that's not true in general (and I'd have to see the rest of the script to know if that's what's being done).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Ah okay. That was an assumption on my part. I can tell you there isn't anything converting columns to arguments in the rest of the script. Basically just goes to that directory, and runs this if statement. So I need to convert the columns in my file to arguments then. Would you be able to help me with that? Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: @CodyThomas Maybe, but I'm very confused about what you're trying to do. Column 349 will have a different value in each line (row) of the file; what line are you trying to check? Also, are the files in plain CSV format, or are there complications like quoted fields (that contain commas), escaped commas, escaped newlines, etc?

Comment: @GordonDavisson It's a file that contains a bunch of data in plain csv format. We have two types of data, quantitative, and qualitative. I need to split the two because they both require different processing. The easiest way to do this I've found is to check for a qualitative result (Which shows up in column 349 of the csv file. If column 349 = negative/positive/pending, then do x, else, do y. all subsequent rows will have the same type of result in the file.

Comment: @CodyThomas So checking field 349 of the first line would be sufficient? If so, `field394="$(head -n1 "$f" | cut -d, -f 349)"; if [[ "$field349" = ...` should work.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you so much. That is exactly what I needed. You have been such a big help. Thanks for taking the time to help someone like me understand what I was doing wrong!

Answer (score 3):

First, I think you're correct that you're missing something, and the syntax highlighting on StackOverflow points it out.

`’` is a unicode character `U+2019`.  This is not a quote that bash accepts.

If you change those quotes to normal `'` quotes, it should help.

Second, you're using a single quote around the string expression you wish to expand.  Bash doesn't expand the contents of single quotes, so `'$3'` turns into the literal expression `$3`.  Double quotes -- `"$3"` -- will expand the value of the variable.

E: Third, as pointed out in the comments, you also need braces around positional parameters greater than 9, so `$11` expands to `${1}1`, whereas `${11}` expands to the value of parameter 11.

E: To be explicit,

```
if [[ "${349}" = 'Negative' ]] || [[ "${349}" = 'Positive' ]] || [[ "${349}" = 'Pending' ]]
```

Also you want to (double) quote the file names when they're being used by `mv`, `rm` and the like.  You don't want a file named `foo bar` to be treated as two files `foo` and `bar`.  You do that correctly in the first part, but then don't on the last two commands.

Comment: `$349` will always be the value of the 3rd positional parameter concatenated with the literal string `49`. There's not enough information in the question to determine what the correct code should be.